# TypeError: bot.commands.get(...).run is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord, discord.js

I've just been trying to make a command handler on discord.js and whenever I run the bot, it throws

> TypeError: bot.commands.get(...).run is not a function

Here's the bottom of the code on where the error is happening.

```js
bot.on("message", async message => {

    if(message.author.bot) return;   
    if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return;

    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);

        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        if(!bot.commands.has(command)) return;


        try {
            bot.commands.get(command).run(bot, message, args);
        } catch (error){
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
})

bot.login(token);
```

Comment: *Does* `bot.commands.get(command)` have a method called `run`?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Sadly it doesn't and I dont know how to make it as of yet because of me being sorta new to javascript and discord.js

Comment: Can you send the code for your command handler please, **IE** the code that loads the commands

Comment: @user15927999 did my answer help you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you command handler is a little bit incomplete.
Here is how I have mine setup, you can try it and tell me if it works (I explain everything with the comments :

```
// your bot.js or main.js file
const bot = new Discord.Client(); // I setup the bot client
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection(); // I create a collection with all the commands

const commandsFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js')); 
// In my project tree, I define all the files with the .js extension in this folder as command files. I will add a file (.js) to this folder for each command I want to create. For example, there will be './commands/ping.js' inside.

for(const file of commandsFiles){
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
// For each command file detected, I add it's name and it's path to my client.commands collection


client.on('message', message => {

  if(message.author.bot) return;   
  if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return;

  if(message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/); 
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(!bot.commands.has(command)) return;
    // if the collection doesn't have a command with this name, return

    try {
      bot.commands.get(command).run(bot, message, args);
      // I get the command object defined previously in the 'for' loop, and I execute the run function with bot, message and args as arguments
    } catch (error){
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

}
```

Now that you have your command handle set up, for each command that you want to create, add a file inside the `./commands/` folder (for example, `./commands/ping.js`, don't forget the .js part).
In this newly created file, write :

```
module.exports = {
  name : 'ping',
  description : 'Ping command',
  run(bot, message, args) {

  // the code to be executed

}
```

Here you can see that we define an object, that will be used by the command handler.

When we do `client.commands.set(command.name, command)` (in bot.js or main.js), we use the name defined here.

When we do `client.commands.get(command).run(bot, message, args)`, we run the `run` function defined inside of the `module.export` object of the targetted command file.

Don't hesitate to tell me if there's anything you don't understand.